# Using XStream to stream an unkown (potentially very large) number of Java objects

Tags: java, xml, stream, xstream

I am attempting to use XStream to stream objects between two processes (which are JVMs essentially). I found a similar question was being asked on this forum before (please refer to following link).

[Best approach to serialize XML to stream with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911773/best-approach-to-serialize-xml-to-stream-with-java)

The basic difference between my requirement and the solution given in the above question is that the all objects being streamed are not available at the beginning of the streaming operation. I want the sending process to wait for new objects and stream them over as and when they come. So this operation can potentially take long time (with lots of idle time between streaming of two objects).

On the other hand in the solution given above works great if we know all the collection elements at the beginning.

Please let me know if anyone encountered such requirement before and able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem into two parts:

1. Communication/connectivity between the processes
2. Serializing each individual object over the connection

For part 1, it's hard to say whether you want to keep one connection alive or open a new connection whenever there's more data. Opening a new connection many, many times can get expensive, so use one connection if you find this cost is too high.

For part 2, it seems cleaner to put object into its own document, rather than trying to fit them all into one. This should be straightforward to implement with XStream. If you need a notion of "done" that similar to sending the final closing tag of an outermost document, then send a custom "done" message when the time is right.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This problem is now solved. I used StAX driver for XStream on the client side and made sure that server sends out the XML document prolog immediately (and not waiting for actual events to occur).

Comment: If you're still using a long running connection, then just make sure you know what will happen if there's a network/connection hiccup and the streaming data is interrupted. I suspect that the StAX driver won't be happy.

Comment: Oh yes. I am caching the last seen object id on the client side. So in case of network/Connection failure, it just reconnects to the server and sends the last seen object id. The server would then respond by transmitting remaining objects after the one seen by the client.